# Why are my SPCI commmands not working with Pyvisa & Python 3.7.9?

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to interface a Keithley 2400 with Python. The connection is correct as when I run my code I get an error on the Keithley itself. However, the actual commands are doing nothing.

Also, when I try to print an output from a command, it prints the number of characters in the string. What is going wrong here? Ultimately I am trying to perform an IV sweep, but right now I am working with this code that is just to make a beep:

```
import pyvisa, serial, time

#Initialize connection + configure ports
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 'COM3'
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.open()

ser.write(str.encode(':OUTP ON')) #turns output on
ser.write(str.encode('*RST')) #resets Keithley
ser.write(str.encode(b':SYST:BEEP:STAT 1')) #turns beeper on
ser.write(bytes(b':SYST:BEEPer200, 1')) #beeps

ser.close()
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks so much!

Comment: `ser.write()` does absolutely nothing other than send characters out the serial port - this is the exact opposite of getting output from a command.  You either need to use `ser.read()`, or actually use the `pyvisa` module that you've imported.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to terminate each command:

```
ser.write(str.encode(':OUTP ON\x0d'))
```